# Configuring Tika With Solr

Tags: solr, apache-tika

I am Looking to index Rich types documents(Pdf, Doc, rtf, txt) into Solr. I found Tika as a solution. I made a rant over the web but didn't found any Docs/links to make it work with ExtractingRequestHandler.

Anyone can please provide step by step way to configure Tika with ExtractingRequestHandler.

Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: In your search for resources, did you try the [ExtractingRequestHandler documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler)?

Comment: I am Currently using Solr-Php-Client Library to index content. Now to index Documents i found tika as a solution. but don't find how to configure it with solr? would you please explain it in brief. or any usefull links/docs?

Comment: To quote the documentation linked above: "Solr's ExtractingRequestHandler uses Tika to allow users to upload binary files to Solr and have Solr extract text from it and then index it."  This isn't a special case, it's just how `ExtractingRequestHandler` works.  The documentation should help you get started.  If you run into trouble as you go, feel free to ask a new question to help in resolving it, but you should give it a try first.

Comment: Thanks @femtoRgon I gone through the documentation. I can't figure out about this line. <str name="tika.config">/my/path/to/tika.config</str>Solr throws an file not found exception. where I can locate this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [ExtractingRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) for Integration of Solr with Tika.
Solr provides tika.config inbuilt and you would not need to define it unless overriding the config.
You can go with the default config as defined in the solrconfig.xml

```
<!-- Solr Cell Update Request Handler

   http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler 

-->
<requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
              startup="lazy"
              class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="lowernames">true</str>
  <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>

  <!-- capture link hrefs but ignore div attributes -->
  <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
  <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
  <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

You can use the commands to index the files to solr with additional metadata.

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=2&literal.title=Test&commit=true&fmap.content=text" -F "myfile=@1.pdf"
```

By default the content of the files are copied to content field and copied over to text, you can override the settings.

Comment: @jayedra One issue ! While indexing other than pdf types it throws an Java.lang.noClassDefFoundError. Any clue ??

Comment: Thanks Jayendra That was a URL issue so jetty was throwing exception anyway solved. But for now I can't see my docs with solr Query *.* whats may wrong any clue?

Comment: @jayedra here is my query:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697019/solr-returns-no-results-for-doc-pdf-images