# link tika 1.16 with solr 6.5.1

Tags: solr, ubuntu-14.04, apache-tika

I have been trying to index scanned PDFs ( every page is an image ). I am able to extract the contents using **apache-tika 1.6**. Now am looking forward to **link / override solr's tika with tika 1.6's jar**. I have tried copying the jars to `solr/contrib/extraction`. I have tried the steps mentioned in this question [Configuring Tika With Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622544/configuring-tika-with-solr) still no luck. 
If I use this command `curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=2&literal.title=Test&commit=true&fmap.content=text" -F "myfile=@1.png"` it indexes properly and also return correct results but its doesn't work for a pdf.
If I try indexing a scanned pdf all I get in `attr_text` is `\n\n\n\n\n undefined \n\n\n`

Comment: Which version of Apache Tika are you using - `1.6` or `1.16`? (They're very different!)

Comment: Hi @Gagravarr I am using tika 1.16